# Search engine optimization queries in Google Analytics Query Explorer 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to fetch the result of Search engine optimization queries in Google Analytics Query Explorer 2. 
[image]

But I am not able to get the desired results. I have tried the below query
[image]

Any suggestions how to achieve this? or Is there a way I can query it using google analytics api.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to download the data from Google Webmaster Tools (after all this is were the queries are tracked before they are imported into Analytics).

Comment: @EikePierstorff No I am trying to get the data from api for my reports . I am using the tool to make my query.

Comment: Webmaster Tools has an API. You will not get the data from GA.

Comment: Webmaster Tools has an API. You will not get the queries from the Analytics API (for one, this is not analytics data - it is not collected by GA. It's merely displayed here when you link GA and Webmaster Tools accounts).

Comment: Can't I fetch the data using Analytics API. My GA and webmaster account are linked.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Checkout Internal Link Checker of Elite Site Optimizer helps in Identifying and fixing the Link Errors

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).